# Nested RecyclerView inside ViewPager inside Fragment not affecting CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have an activity with a coordinatorlayout with a FrameLayout inside it. Inside the Framelayout is a Viewpager and one of the Fragments in the Viewpager contains a Recyclerview. Is it possible to have that RecyclerView affect the topmost CoordinatorLayout?

Thanks.

main.xml (Activity xml layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <!-- This is the container to all other fragments. -->
            <!-- The only other ones are in the view pager. -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- Side Menu -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

root fragment of activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent">-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    <!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment inside Viewpager

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: So you have a vertical RecyclerView within a ViewPager page and you want to hide the toolbar once you scroll vertically UP in the RecyclerView, right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an interface object that can communicate between the fragment in the recycler view and the main activity.

Check this video out on how to create such interface in a slightly different use case but I think it might help because it helped me solve slightly similar problem to yours:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHHXxWbSaho

Cheers!